# how to update row in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a `DataGridView` that is populated from a DataSet.

How can I change any cell in the `DataGridView`, and have this change the DataSet too (and the Database).

Is there a sample program for this (in C#) that I can learn from?

Comment: Have you tried googling on Databinding and DataGridView tutorials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3718691/Working-with-the-DataGridView-Control.htm) with clear explanations, screenshots, and code that demonstrates how to use the DataGridView.  The data binding sections should be of particular interest.

Comment: This was an answer when you wrote this answer, but now it's not. Please copy/paste the relevant bits into this answer (keeping the link as attribution).

Answer (score 1):

```
DataRowView drv = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
DataRow[] rowsToUpdate = new DataRow[] { drv.Row };

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Categories", con);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Update(rowsToUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a program to change the contents of the DataGridView, just change the underlying Dataset.  The DataSet has methods to commit those changes to the Database as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRowView drv = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
DataRow[] rowsToUpdate = new DataRow[] { drv.Row };

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Categories", con);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Update(rowsToUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a app which is connected to access database. In this app, I've done like this:

```
try
{
 con.Open();

 foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
 {
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdTxt, con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("kurs", c2);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", item.Cells[0].Value);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
 MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
}
finally
{
 con.Close();
}
```

If your database in sql server, then u can use SQlDbCommand class.