# C# Datagrid View

Tags: c#, datagridview

Im new to c#

trying to do an update statement from a data grid in c#, basically im doing the following to try and carry the value to the update statement, can someone tell me the correct way to reference the cells so that it takes the value as a string in to the sql statement, iv been doing it like this, but obviously its wrong.

```
 AssetNumberV = dgvAssetCost.CurrentCell.ToString();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update row in DataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2135737/299327)

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code :

```
string item = dataGridView1["columnName", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this in winforms? If so, something like this may help;

```
 string Result =  dgvAssetCost.Rows[dgvAssetCost.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["columnNameHere"].Value.ToString();
```

Here you're referencing a row, which is gathered on your cell onclick event, and then giving it the column name.