# Changes from datagridview not being saved in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have this form,when I give it some ID and click the highlighted button,shows me some info in a datagridview taken from a database.
[First Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DclG9.png)

The code of the button is here:

```
 private void kerkoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {               
            Konektimi();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Vizita WHERE PacientiId=@pacientiId";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pacientiId",pacientiTextBox.Text);                                            
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            dt.Load(reader);
                            forma.vizitaDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
                            forma.ShowDialog();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Nuk ka të dhëna për këtë pacient");
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Suposing that we get something from the database we get this:
[Second Form,with the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLJaw.png)

This is a new form that will be opened after clicking the kerkoButton.

NOW,the problem is this: When I edit a row(or some rows),if I click Save,the changes will not be saved in the database.
What should i do?
Could I make a SaveButton in this datagridform?If yes,how?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "[how to update row in DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135737/how-to-update-row-in-datagridview)"

You can access the edited row by using the property `CurrentRow` of your DataGridView like so:

```
DataRowView dataRowView = yourDataGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
DataRow[] rowsToUpdate = new DataRow[] { dataRowView.Row };

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Vizita", con);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Update(rowsToUpdate);
```

Alternatively, if you want to update all edited rows at once, you have to create a flag and set it to `true` whenever you change a property using the `PropertyChanged` event.

When clicking "Save" you iterate through all rows and add the edited ones to `rowsToUpdate`.

Comment: If you make proper use of data binding the DataTable will track its own changes and all you need to do is call Update on the adapter. If you are iterating over grid rows you are doing it wrong.